# Binding closevotes should be recorded for moderators as they are for gold badge owners

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, close-reasons, moderators

When a question is closed by a user with gold tag badge, this fact is explicitly noted in the database. E.g., for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25954070/) the PostHistory table has

```
"Voters":[{"Id":100297,"DisplayName":"Martijn Pieters","BindingReason":{"GoldTagBadge":"list"}}]
```

and this information makes it possible to render the closure banner with an informative notice about the single-handed closure: *Users with the [list] gold badge can single-handedly mark [list] questions as duplicates*.

Moderators also have a binding closevote, but it's not recorded in the database in a similar way. The diamonds appearing to their name in closure banner only reflect the current moderator status. This means that as moderators change and their moderatorship period is forgotten, the sites fill with unexplained single-handed closure banners, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/375958/):

[image: banner example]

I propose to record the use of moderator's binding vote, e.g., as

```
"BindingReason":{"UserStatus":"moderator"}
```

and render the closure banner accordingly: e.g., greyed-out diamond with tooltip *User had a binding close vote, being a moderator at the time.*

If changing SEDE schema is too much hassle, at least give some clue to past mod status in the banner, using [the internal isBinding  flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240169/binding-closevotes-should-be-recorded-for-moderators-as-they-are-for-gold-badge#comment786793_240169).

Comment: Internally, there's an "IsBinding" flag on the vote for both mods and badge-holders; would simply exposing this in the UI satisfy this request?

Comment: Yes, the closure banners was the main reason I brought this up. Information being accessible through Data Explorer would be nice to have, but this is a secondary  aspect (one might want to analyse statistics of mod-closures versus regular closures).