# Keep track of historical user (moderator) status and make available in profile

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, stack-exchange, moderators

Every now and then, I could be browsing new answers that come in on older questions in Stack Overflow and might come across answers/comments from users that are now moderators.  I might even see one answering newer questions.

More importantly, when I browse meta sites and see a conversation of a moderator--especially older conversations--sometimes I would want to know in what state of mind the user was when they were in that conversation.  Were they moderators [at the time of the conversation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138603/the-moderator-diamonds-present-or-past)?  Or did it just happen to be a conversation that happened before they were appointed?  I think it would be important to be able to distinguish statements that were personal opinions or official policy.

**Can the history of a user's status be tracked and be made available to users?**
**Perhaps as a privilege or just widely available.  Maybe on-demand only (like with vote counts).**

If the user was a moderator then but is no longer now, then it shouldn't be any different, they just appear as a regular user.  But may want to note that they were formerly a moderator and show in the history.  But I would understand if it was not shown for former moderators.

I'm not particularly interested in other user status, such as first registered, bans, hard deletions, or anything regarding unregistered users, that could be too intrusive.  But I wouldn't oppose if it was made more general.

Only for the more important status types:

- Moderator
- Stack Exchange Developer ([or maybe not?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77883/differentiate-between-employees-and-moderators))
- Other Stack Exchange Employee (ditto)

Possibly even other *major* status milestones for regular users.

- Reached 10k
- Reached 20k

It doesn't need to be more detailed than it needs to be.  The start date and the end date is more than enough.  I don't need to know why it ended or how it started.

Comment: Slightly related: [Deletion votes from users who later became moderators shouldn't prevent community undeletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174860/deletion-votes-from-users-who-later-became-moderators-shouldnt-prevent-communit), and its comments referring to the existence of a "mod election table". Which I guess is also used for http://stackoverflow.com/election and all.

Comment: It would be great if comments and edit/close/delete/... actions (and posts on Metas) could show the hollow diamond ◊ if posted while being a moderator, and not show any diamond if not, even if currently a moderator.

Comment: The only current way to see past *elected* moderators is to visit the /election page of a site, eg. http://superuser.com/election - that shows you that *currently* there are 2 people who were elected but are no longer moderators. However, this only works for *elected* moderators, and not pro-tem mods when a site is first made, so it doesn't work as well... So this would be a *very* useful feature. In fact, even if this information was put in the SE  API, it would be handy - scripts and such could be made to utilise this info; the JSON could simply have an extra `was_moderator: true/false`! :)

Comment: Related: [Binding closevotes should be recorded for moderators as they are for gold badge owners](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240169)